# Last record saved in a table over one column

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have data:

```
CLIENT_NO , DATE , TYPE
CLIENT 1- 22/09/2014 -001
CLIENT 1- 19/09/2014 -002
CLIENT 1- 10/09/2014 -005
CLIENT 2- 15/09/2014 -012
CLIENT 2- 20/09/2014 -011
```

I want to have latest TYPE stored in this table over time for each client. How can I do that using PL/SQL?

Comment: Please disable your CAPS LOCK and then [edit] both your question and title to write it in proper case. Text in ALL CAPS is difficult to read and understand, and won't get you an answer any faster. It's also very impotlite to SHOUT at us when you're asking us for *free help* to solve *your problem*.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't really need PL/SQL; pure SQL will do.

One option is to *sort* them (analytic functions as `row_number` or `rank` help in this case), and then fetch rows with row number = 1 (because of `order by` clause which sorts them by date value in descending order).

```
SQL> with
  2  test (client_no, datum, type) as
  3  -- sample data
  4    (select 'client 1', date '2014-09-22', '001' from dual union all
  5     select 'client 1', date '2014-09-19', '002' from dual union all
  6     select 'client 1', date '2014-09-10', '005' from dual union all
  7     select 'client 2', date '2014-09-15', '012' from dual union all
  8     select 'client 2', date '2014-09-20', '011' from dual
  9    ),
 10  -- sort them
 11  sorted as
 12    (select client_no, datum, type,
 13       row_number() over (partition by client_no order by datum desc) rn
 14     from test
 15    )
 16  -- select the one with RN = 1
 17  select client_no, datum, type
 18  from sorted
 19  where rn = 1;

CLIENT_NO  DATUM      TYPE
---------- ---------- ----
client 1   22/09/2014 001
client 2   20/09/2014 011

SQL>
```